# Function to repeat letters

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that takes a string and returns a string in which each character is repeated once.

This is code I have so far:

```
function doubleChar(str) {
  var split = str.split(); 
  var repeat = split.map(function (split) {
      return split += split;
  });     
  var n = repeat.join();
  return n;
}
```

I know this is wrong but I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Sounds like homework to me, lol

Comment: `return split + split;` not `return split += split;`! And `str.split(''); ` not `str.split(); `!

Comment: How is it wrong? What's it doing (or not doing)?

Comment: i pretty sure you mean `.join('')` instead `.join()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` and `join` both need an argument.

`split('')` and `join('')`.

`'abc'.split()` returns `['abc']` but `'abc'.split('')` returns `['a','b','c']`.

`['a','b','c'].join()` returns `'a,b,c'` but `['a','b','c'].join('')` returns `'abc'`

Comment: Neither needs an argument

Comment: @j08691, by default `.join()` equal `.join(',')`

Comment: Yes it does. The default for `join` is `','`. `'abc'.join()` returns `'a,b,c'` not `'abc'`.

Comment: No, neither `.split()` nor `join()` requires an argument. Read the docs. Both have defaults but an argument is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it with `Array#join` and `String#split`.

```js
var str = 'homework';

console.log(str.split('').map(v => v.repeat(2)).join(''));
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP

Comment: @ChrisCharles I've just suggested him an easier way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Will run in old browsers

```
function doubleChars(str) {
    var chars = "";
    for (var i=0, n=str.split("").length; i<n; i++) {
        chars += str[i] + str[i];
    }
    return chars;
}
```